# Why can't break the line with vim command properly?

Tags: regex, vim

```
flip   翻转[左右变成右左] fork  叉子\分岔\岔口\复刻
:%s/^\([ a-zA-Z]\+\)\([\U4E00-\U9FFF ]\+.\+\)\([ a-zA-Z]\+\)\([\U4E00-\U9FFF ]\+.\+\)$/\1;\2\3;\4/g
```

It was changed into

```
flip   ;翻转[左右变成右左] fork  ;叉子\分岔\岔口\复刻
```

I want to break it into two lines when to add  semicolon with just one vim command.

Three different regular expressions were tried,same wrong result displayed on my vim.(debian+vim).

```
:%s/^\([ a-zA-Z]\+\)\([\U4E00-\U9FFF ]\+.\+\)\([ a-zA-Z]\+\)\([\U4E00-\U9FFF ]\+.\+\)$/\1;\2\r\3;\4/g
:%s/^\([ a-zA-Z]\+\)\([\U4E00-\U9FFF ]\+.\+\)\([ a-zA-Z]\+\)\([\U4E00-\U9FFF ]\+.\+\)$/\1;\2\n\3;\4/g
:%s/^\([ a-zA-Z]\+\)\([\U4E00-\U9FFF ]\+.\+\)\([ a-zA-Z]\+\)\([\U4E00-\U9FFF ]\+.\+\)$/\1;\2\r\n\3;\4/g
```

[image]

How to get the following output with just one vim command?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work:

```
:%s/^\([a-zA-Z ]\+\)\([^a-zA-Z ]\+\) \([a-zA-Z ]\+\)\([^a-zA-Z ]\+\)$/\1\2\r\3\4/g
```

That just adds `\r` to the replacement in the right place where it seems you want the line break.

It also simplifies things by just saying, Look for any number of alpha characters or space at the beginning of the line, followed by any number of characters that are not alpha characters or spaces, followed by a space, followed by any number of alpha characters or space, followed by any number of characters that are not alpha characters or spaces before the end of the line.

Comment: My regular expression make white spaces into the 3th group.

Comment: :%s/^\([a-zA-Z ]\+\)\([^a-zA-Z ]\+\) \([a-zA-Z ]\+\)\([^a-zA-Z ]\+\)$/\1;\2\r\3;\4/g